# How to make a train turning movement?

Tags: game-physics

I'm trying to develop a train-like game in which the player will move along a pre-determined track. And I'm having a trouble to make a function to turn and move the player along the track. The game will only have L and U turns (90 and 180 degrees) throughout the level, FYI. So my question is, how do you make a movement function that will make the player turn and move along his track / trajectory, regardless of speed (there will be different type of "trains" with different speed settings) and FPS (the devices will vary so the FPS can also vary). This is what I've done so far:

```
/// <summary>
/// Rotate and translate each tick if we are turning.
/// This will be called each tick when we are at a junction and need to turn.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dt"> The delta time in mili seconds. </param>
/// <param name="turnRate"> The turn rate each second in degree. + if CW, - if CCW. </param>
/// <param name="targetHeading"> The target angle in degree. Can be 0, 90, 180, 270. In world space coordinate. </param>
/// <param name="speed"> The speed of the train. </param>
void TurnAndMoveEachTick(float dt, float turnRate, float targetHeading, float speed)
{
    float currentHeading = getHeading();
    float nextHeading = currentHeading + turnRate * dt; //Get thenext  heading this tick

    //Clamp the turning based on the targetHeading
    if ( (turnRate > 0.0 && nextHeading > targetHeading) ||
         (turnRate < 0.0 && nextHeading < targetHeading)   )
        nextHeading = targetHeading;

    //Turn
    this.rotate(nextHeading, Coordinate::WORLD); //Rotate to nextHeading usng the world space coordinate.

    //Move
    float displacement = speed * dt;
    this.translateBy(getHeading(), displacement); //Translate by displacement with the direction of the new heading.
}
```

When I tried this using a different speed, it gets very wrong. So I must also adjust the turnRate accordingly. But by how many? That's what I don't get. And also, I think this function will also be screwed if the FPS drops down (I tried this on my pretty high end workstation) since the delta time each tick will also be different. So how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is difficult to see what exactly is not working. What is the unexpected output? Two observations: a) turnRate depends on speed, so it would be better to just hand over the speed and let this function calculate the turn rate.  b) dt has to be calculated by saving the current time for the next call to this function. Then you can measure the time difference.

Comment: You could handle the calculation of heading differently by using the distance travelled as the paramenter. When you enter a turn, calculate the total distance travelled within this turn by adding variable speed*dt at each time step. This will also yield a heading that is independent of an FPS.

Comment: a. Yeah that's what I had in mind. But I don't know how to calculate the turnRate based on the speed. For example we have a U-turn track that is basically a half-circle with a diameter of 10 meters. How do I calculate the turnRate of a train with, for example, speed of 60 km/h? Or 100 km/h? That's not even using the varied dt based on the FPS. b. I'm not sure I understand. If you're saying what a dt is, I am well aware of what exactly a delta time is. What I meant was a dt when the game runs at, for example, 20 FPS will be different as 40 FPS each tick. How do I factor that into the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turnRate in degrees is speed / circumference * dt * 360

circumference is 2*pi*radius

For a fixed FPS of 20, you would get dt=0.05. Be careful with your example of 100 km/h and a radius of only 10 m, because you only spend a few ticks in the turn. Based on your code example, it is no surprise that the train is not on the track any more :)

As I suggested in the comment, I would discard the turnRate concept and use distance as the parameter to calculate the angle at which the train is travelling at a given point in time. Just add the current speed*dt to a distance, then

angle = distance / circumference * 360

No need to fiddle with a turnRate, that will just accumulate errors made in every tick.

Does this help?

Comment: I think I understand what you meant. I'll try it then. I'll consider this the answer. Thanks.